# How to distinguish/target extension-less files? (Command Batch, Windows 10)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I'm working with files with various extensions, such as .bmp, .txt, etc, and I'm in the process of sorting them around through a batch file. However there are some files without any extension that I would like to be able to specifically manipulate.

How can I target extension-less files alone? Such as moving/deleting them exclusively. Or moving files with extensions while ignoring extension-less files?

Comment: to isolate extensionless files: `@For /f delims^= %%G in ('dir /b *.* /A:-D')Do @if "%%~xG"=="" Echo(%%G`

Comment: Thank you @T3RR0R. Not sure why there isn't a closing bracket at the end, but it works!

Comment: There is no opening parenthesis too. The `(` in `echo(` doesn't work as an opening for a code block but is a safeguard against an empty variable. Try `echo %emptyvar%` vs. `echo(%emptyvar%` (yes, agreed, this is strange...)

Comment: As an additional note, you could also use the following syntax, `…@If "%%G" == "%%~nG"…`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to view or process files with an extension, use this syntax:
`dir /b /a-d [path] | findstr /l "."`
Only files containing a dot will be displayed.
You can add this to the for statement to get the output to a processable variable.
Of course, you must add an escape character before the pipe character in the for sentence.
However, to perform the operation in the subdirectories as well, it is best to use the for sentence, as a dot may appear in the folder name. like this:
`for /f "tokens=*" %d in ('dir /s /b /ad') do @dir /b /a-d "%d" | findstr /l "."`
To do the opposite (showing only files without an extension) simply add the `findstr /v` parameter.